# CURL is not following 301 Redirects, what do I need to do?

Tags: c++, http, curl, http-status-code-301

I am using the CURL c++ api to get quotes from Yahoo's financial API.  The curl api and my code seem to be working fine, however I am getting a "301" redirect message when I tell CURL to visit the url I want.  How can I get CURL to follow through to the 301 redirect and get the data I want?

Here is the URL I am using:

```
http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?e=.csv&s=WSF,WSH&f=b2b3s
```

Here is the response I am getting:

```
<HEAD><TITLE>Redirect</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black">
<FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>
 "<em>http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?e=.csv&s=WSF,WSH,WSM,WSO,WST,WTI,WTM,WTR,WTS,WTU,WTW,WU,WWE,WWW,WX,WXS,WY,WYN,X,XAA,XCJ,XCO,XEC,XEL,XEL-A,XEL-E,XFB,XFD,XFH,XFJ,XFP,XFR,XIN,XJT,XKE,XKK,XKN,XKO,XL,XL-Y,XOM,XRM,XRX,XVF,XVG,Y,YGE,YPF,YSI,YUM,YZC,ZB-A,ZB-B,ZB-C,ZEP,ZF,ZLC,ZMH,ZNH,ZQK,ZTR,ZZ,ZZC&f=b2b3ccd1d2ghjkk2k3l2l3mm2m3m4m5m6m7m8opst7vw</em>".<p></B></FONT>

<!-- default "Redirect" response (301) -->
</BODY>
```

Here are my CURL init options

```
CURL *eh = curl_easy_init();

curl_easy_setopt(eh, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, cb);
curl_easy_setopt(eh, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt(eh, CURLOPT_URL, url);
curl_easy_setopt(eh, CURLOPT_PRIVATE, url);
curl_easy_setopt(eh, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0L);

curl_multi_add_handle(cm, eh);
```

I didn't post my code, as it is all working, I just need the general method of following through woth the 301's with CURL.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the PHP world, the option is named `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`. I assume the constant names are standardized and come from the same header file, so this should work for you.

```
curl_easy_setopt(eh, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

(or whatever "boolean true" is in this context.)

Alternatively, when receiving a `30x` status code, you can parse the `Location` header manually for the new address. Obviously though, the "follow location" option is much easier, as it doesn't require a second request.